# My Microservice isn't listening for Messages on Cloudamqp

Tags: typescript, rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

I am currently working on an eCommerce platform that uses a microservices-based architecture using NestJS, so I am creating a checkout service where the admin can access all the checkout sessions and the details of an individual checkout session on the client-side using the AMQP protocol and cloudamqp (a managed cloud-based message-broker managing my queues)

Here is my code on the main.ts file

```js
import { NestFactory, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './shared/filters/all-exceptions.filter';
import { DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger/dist/document-builder';
import { SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PermissionGuard } from './shared/guards/permissions.guard';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { RpcValidationFilter } from './shared/filters/rcpc-exceptions.filter';

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.RMQ,
      options: {
        urls: [process.env.RMQ_URL],
        queue: 'checkout-svc-messages',
        queueOptions: {
          durable: false,
        },
      },
    }
  );
  app.useGlobalFilters(new RpcValidationFilter());
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }));
  app.listen(() => console.log('Checkout Microservice is listening'));
}
bootstrap();
```

However, when starting the application, the microservice doesn't start to listen for messages

Here's what I mean[image]

It just stays on this loading state on end without any changes.
I have double-checked my code and also cross-referenced it with the docs and other sources and my code implementation seems to be correct

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Does it contact the server at all? You can read the logs for dedicated instances in CloudAMQP and see. Contact us at support@cloudamqp.com and we can help you out

Comment: @jrhodin i am currently using the free plan for development purposes and I don't think it is contacting the cloudamqp server  because the number of connections is still zero

Comment: Yes you need to find some debug switch here to get more logging out.
If you let us know which vhost it is (via email, don't publish it here) we can search the server side logs and see.

Comment: Ok sir i am sending the vhost server via email in a bit